# convert special charecters in URL GET/POST Request java

Tags: java, string, web, get

I have one problem how I can convert in Java this:

```
String word="Conformément";
```

to

this:

```
String word = "Conform%C3%A9ment";
```

The second is transformed when the string is passed through web.

Thanks in advance,
Mihail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what part of the URI you wish this word to be inserted in.

Your best bet is to use a library which supports [URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). And (shameless plug) [I have one which works](https://github.com/fge/uri-template).

Simply create a template and fill the correct values. I can help you create the template as well.

And no, `URLEncoder.encode()` does **not** work for this job. Quoting the README of that project:

> There is a very common misconception with this method. It does NOT encode strings for use in URIs, it encodes strings for use in POST data, that is for application/x-www-form-urlencoded data; and in this encoding, spaces become +, not %20!

Here is an example of a template where the word would appear in the query part:

```
http://my.site/some/where?word={word}
```

Using the library above, the code would be:

```
final URITemplate tmpl = new URITemplate("http://my.site/some/where?word={word}");
final VariableMapBuilder builder = VariableMap.newBuilder();
builder.addScalarValue("word", "Conformément");
tmpl.toString(builder.freeze()); // returns the correct result
// Or:
tmpl.toURI(builder.freeze());
tmpl.toURL(builder.freeze());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
String encodedWord = URLEncoder.encode(word, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi, I need the opposite combination.Something like é -> %C3%A9

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `URLEncoder.encode()` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding) other thread.